# mysqli prepare debugging works not full

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am working the first time with mysqli prepare.
Now I would like to handle the errors.
I tried this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myColumn` = ?" );
if ( $sql && $sql->bind_param("s", $value = 1) && $sql->execute() ) {
        
    $result = $sql->get_result();
            
    while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {
        // ...
    }
    
    $sql->close();
        
} else {
    echo $sql->error;
    echo $db->error;
}

$db->close();
```

This works fine !
For example: If I modify the sql syntax (wrong table name, wrong column name, ...) I get correctly the $db->error.

But If the sql syntax is correct and I modify the $sql->bind_param like this:

```
$sql->bind_param("X", $value = 1)
```

I get no $sql->error and no $db->error.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Why not check what each of the three statements in your `if` resolve to in case of error?

Comment: Do not bind the value within the function. Set `$value` to 1, then add just the $value to the bind_param

Comment: FYI, that's a horrible method of "debugging"

Comment: and which version for debugging is better ???

Comment: it is linked at the top of your question

Comment: as you can see, with proper debugging you can see every error, and without any "debugging" code: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/18eb468bc4848b2b2b1c2f23162d9128/